# How to Call .exe file from Windows Store Apps?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I m trying to call a dextop application say 'MyApp.exe' from my Windows Store App to process some values; Usual way is to use Process from System.Diagnostic to call .exe files but that's not allowed with Windows Store App. I don't need to publish, Kindly guide with some hacks to run a exe with button click from Windows Store App

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to publish the app, you can use LoadPackagedLibrary http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and follow below steps to launch an executable.

If you are familiar with writing DLLs

1. Create a Win32 DLL, say LauncherDLL.dll and export a function
2. In the function implementation, use CreateProcessEx to launch your MyApp.exe
3. Then add the LauncherDLL.dll to your Windows store application
4. Use LoadPackagedLibrary to load LauncherDLL.dll and then get the address of the function using GetProcAddress.
5. Call the exported function which in turn launches MyApp.exe

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/win8devsupport/archive/2012/12/20/porting-desktop-apps-to-windows-store-apps.aspx for more details

Comment: Basically I have my Matlab code for processing which i want to use, Can I use its dll inside windows store app?

Comment: Yes, you can. But you need to add the DLL to windows store application [Open windows store application project properties, Click Add, then Add an existing item. Select the DLL you want to add to the project.] Once the DLL is added, use LoadPackageLibrary to load the DLL and call GetProcAddress to retrieve the exported function address and call the function. Note: if the DLL has any dependencies, you need to add those dependencies too. Else, you can follow the steps mentioned in prior answer, and in LauncherDLL.dll, load your matlab DLL and call the functions.

Comment: Yes I tried to do it, But the project started to crash stop; I've not used LoadPackageLibrary at that time, Can you please refer to some example for using LoadPackageLibrary?

Comment: Please see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/win8devsupport/archive/2012/12/20/porting-desktop-apps-to-windows-store-apps.aspx . At the end of the article you would find information related to DLL creation, exporting a function and using LoadPackagedLibrary

Comment: What if you need to publish the app?

Answer (score -1):

Windows Store apps are `.appx` files, not `.exe` files. So, you can not save them as `.exe` files without a translator that I don't even know exists.

Comment: This question is about launching a `.exe` as a subprocess from a Windows Store app.  It's not about renaming anything.